# How to access MySQL from a remote computer (not localhost)?

Tags: mysql, networking

I have my dev environment set up as a Ubuntu Server (with LAMP installation) inside a vmware. The vmware is running on my local windows 7 machine. When I try to access my mysql server via HeidiSQL program the connection fails. I get a:

```
Server Error 2003, can't connect to mysql server on <IP ADRESS HERE>
```

I can however access the db server via PhpMyAdmin. MySQL is running and my connection credentials and port are all correct.

I read that you should enter the IPs of the computer you are trying to connect from as the "bind address" in the my.cnf file. Which I did. I tried both the internal network IP as well as the online IP. Still no luck, same message.

Since this isn't a production environment I would ideally like to allow anyone to access that server, not limit it by IP. Especially since my ISP assigns dynamic IPS. So I would have to change it all the time, assuming that even works.

So does anyone know how I can connect to my MySQL server from a remote computer?

P.S. I assume this is something developers have to deal with that's why I posted it here and not Super User. If it must be migrated please send it to Server Fault not Super User.

Comment: Check your Connection string here  http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Heidi SQL I was able to get it to work following the instructions on this article:

http://mysql-tools.com/en/articles/http-tunnel/73-heidisql-a-http-tunnel.html

It uses a program called HTTP Tunnel. It's a lot slower but at least it works. If you use Navicat it comes with a PHP file that you can upload to your server and it will connect via that.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, be aware this gives the world and his dog access to your mysql server.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

But say you are on your home network of 192.168.1.2/16 then you can at least limit it like this.

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'192.168.%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Another option is that you have a user and password but want to connect from anywhere

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'mysecretuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecretpassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: sorry total noob here, where do I enter this, in mysql monitor? or add it to the cnf file?

Comment: This would be through a connection to the mysql database via a client.

Comment: So I tried entering the 1st in the mysql command line, it said 1 row affected. Then I rebooted the server and tried to connect once again from the remote machine and still the same error.

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled on the mysql box?

Answer (score 1):

first check the ip assigned to vmware using from cmd

```
ipconfig/all
```

suppose ipassigned to vmware is 192.168.11.1
now in vmware in ubuntu check the ipadress

```
ifconfig
```

suppose ip adress of ubuntu is 192.168.11.137
now open mysql configurations

sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
change the bind address to ubuntu ip address

```
bind-address = 192.168.11.137
```

restart mysql
now connect to mysql

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and create a user with all privileges and host ip of vmware i.e 192.168.11.1

```
GRANT ALL ON db.* TO user@'192.168.11.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

now try to connect from windows.
also open port of mysql

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

restart mysql and try to connect on ubuntu host ip address 192.168.11.137