# unable to retrive enteries from mysql database of phpmyadmin(wamp) from other pc

Tags: java, php, mysql, wamp

i have created a mysql database using phpmyadmin(wamp). i can see database from other pc using ip address of my pc. however when i run java code to retrive the entries from the database it gives error. we have already disabled firewall of host pc.
here is my code :

```
/*
```

> - To change this template, choose Tools | Templates  * and open the
>     template in the editor.  */ package wamp;
>
> import java.sql.Connection;import java.sql.DriverManager; import
>   java.sql.ResultSet; import java.sql.SQLException; import
>   java.sql.Statement;
>
> /**  *  * @author user  */ public class Wamp {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

    // TODO code application logic here
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
{
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/test","root",""); 
                Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
              // stmt.executeUpdate("Insert into student values(1,'abc','nagpur')");
                ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("Select names from sample where id=15");
                rs.next();
               String name= rs.getString("names");               
                System.out.println(name);
                System.out.println("DOne..");
               //INSERT INTO `student`(`id`, `name`, `address`) VALUES (1,'amol','nagpur');
            con.close();

          }
catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
    System.out.println("error"+e);
}

}

}
```

here is error message:

```
errorjava.sql.SQLException: null, message from server: "Host 'user-PC.Home' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

in your phpmyadmin sql interface

Answer (score 2):

This is because you did not give your other PC the correct permissions to connect the MySQL Database, if you'd search the error on google you would find the answer:

At first ping user-PC to get his IP address:

```
Ping user-PC
```

Then login to the MySQL Database and give

> user-PC's IP address

permissions to connect the MySQL Database:

```
use mysql
GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'user-PC' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-root-password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not granting permission for remote access.To access mysql from remote system you have to grant permission.
Try the following ways

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Above will give access to all but if you want to give access to some particular IP of your home network then try this way

```
 GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'192.168.%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Following links may help you

[link1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html)

[link2](http://mysql-tools.com/en/articles/http-tunnel/73-heidisql-a-http-tunnel.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse of you didin't grant the access to other pc in samew network:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to '%'@'192.168.%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

similar question link:[How to access MySQL from a remote computer (not localhost)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453993/how-to-access-mysql-from-a-remote-computer-not-localhost)