# Accessing MYSQL from a remote computer

Tags: mysql

Good afternoon,

I am trying to give public access to a mysql database setup in a client's server (windows server 2012), so that my application can send it some info during the day. The application will be positioned around my country so a local connection is out of the question. I have followed many solutions to this problem posted by many users but none works, but I apologize if you feel this has been asked and answered.

For starters the database is working on the 3306 default port and an online port scanner detects the port as open (I contacted my ISP so they could open the port).

I edited mysql config file "my.ini" to comment the bind-address value so that it listens on any of the ips it's connected to (localhost. lan and public ip).
I can connect to the database using the mysql.exe on the 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.129 (local lan) but when i try using either the public ip address or my hostname (a dyndns.org domain name that resolves to my public ip address) I get the following error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (10061)

My questions are:
Can this be a firewall problem even when my port checks out as open? Even with the port open it can still be a port forwarding problem, correct? Should I ask my ISP to port forward all request on 3306 port to be sent to a specific machine?

Comment: what's your server ? `APACHE` or `IIS`?

Comment: If present, comment out `skip-networking` in my.cnf

Comment: Also, you'll need to ensure that your database `GRANT`s are permitting external user connections See [the `GRANT` docs for details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski does it secure ? i don't think it.Good thing is using a STATIC IP on client PC and allowed it on server

Comment: @samitha It is always less secure to permit external connections to the database, if SSL isn't used, but that's what the OP is asking for.

Comment: As mentioned by samitha, it's important to note that all these restrictions ar there for security purpose, so you should be very carefull before removing it. The way you're going is like letting the doors of your house open so that  your friends can come in when they arrive... but you never know which stranger may pass in the street...

Comment: @samitha I installed easyphp on a computer that already has an iis server installed but my application only needs mysql. I will not be using the apache or the iis components. For now i'd rather not try the httptunnel option since the http ports are closed and requires another wait time from the ISP and would probably lead me to more frustration.

Comment: @RicardoMota use SSH tunnel .that's very best solution

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I have given the root user access on any machine. And I am not specifiying any database when connecting. just the server and user with ">mysql -h 80.80.80.80 -u root"

Comment: @samitha What do you mean best solution? Are you talking about security?

Comment: Thank you. But at this point I need my current solution to work without having to rewrite my code and finding a ssh solution that works with an arm linux distribution. I can worry about security on another phase of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all the suggestions on the other threads are correct. For your MySQL server to be accessible from a public machine you need to remove the bind-address line in MySQL config file (my.ini). The server should start listening on any of it's available networks.
Then you need to create a user with a proper privileges to access your database remotelly. using this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/8454003/1338401.

The parts that was causing me problems was the firewall/router configurations. You need to open the door your server is listening in and portforward it to your server machine. In my case I have no access to the router so I had to contact my ISP and instruct them to open the port and port forward it.

As many people pointed out MySQL connects using an unencrypted  tcp/ip connection and this solution should not be used due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access your database is to use a ssh tunnel.
Most of database client allow you to do this (MySQL Workbench for example if your OS is windows).

The idea is to connect via ssh on the remote server and then open a mysql connexion with the localhost ip.

Search in google for "database ssh tunnel" or "mysql ssh tunnel".

Comment: Wouldn't this require a complete rewrite of my application that currently uses Connector/J to connect to the MySQL server?

Comment: About mysql security, look at the doc : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security-guidelines.html

Comment: You could simply develop a little secured CRUD webservice (depending of your needed, you could only develop the Read part) on the mysql server.

Comment: I have been considering a CRUD webservice for my next iteration. And thank you all for your help.