# Cannot Access MySQL installed in Virtual Machine

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine, vmware

I install MySQL in xubuntu 15.04 which is installed in VMware.
This is the detail of MySQL:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
```

I have set netstat.

```
@ubuntu:~$ netstat -an|grep 3306
tcp     0   0 127.0.0.1:3306        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Also, I removed **bind_address** & **skip-externak-locking** in **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** (I cannot find those two in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**. I only found them in mysqld.cnf.) and retart mysql.

I also set the user of MySQL:

```
mysql> create user 'test'@'localhost' identified by 'MY_PASSWORD';
mysql> create user 'test'@'%' identified by 'MY_PASSWORD';
mysql> grant all on *.* to 'test'@'localhost';
mysql> grant all on *.* to 'test'@'%';
```

As https://stackoverflow.com/a/21382716/1618596 says, I open port of mysql:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

---

Then I want to access the database in my local machine.
I use Java with Hibernate. This is the code of hibernate.cfg.xml (192.168.96.130 is my xubuntu's ip address)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.96.130/Test_DB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">MY_PASSWORD</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But it shows error:

```
WARN: HHH000277: Could not bind factory to JNDI
org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name []
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.bind(JndiServiceImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.addSessionFactory(SessionFactoryRegistry.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at M.main(M.java:14)
```

Therefore, I want to know how I can access my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the **name** attribute from your opening session factory tag in your hibernate configuration file so that your `hibernate.xml` looks like this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.96.130/Test_DB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">MY_PASSWORD</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. It is so unbelievable the issue is so simple... just because of an attribute.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because the hibernate generation tools are not as up to date with the latest versions of hibernate. As of today, you will get this error with the Hibernate Core 4.3.10 Final and JBoss Tools 4.2.3 Final versions (both latest versions considered).